# jQuery.parseJSON giving error unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting this JSON from server

```
"{"name": "abcd,e"abc"ssfgh", "location": {"latitude": 21.1484436189,"longitude": 79.093036862},"id": "12345"}"
```

I know issue in this JSON is (") in the value of name.
But problem is I cant change JSON(As I am getting it from server).
So now how to parse it? I want to convert this JSON string to object.

`jQuery.parseJSON` is giving error.

Edit:

Here is what I am doing to parse this JSON string
 var body_json = jQuery.parseJSON(JSONString);

Comment: show your code also. you need to escape the quotes before parsing.

Comment: It should be the server's responsibility to send a valid JSON, otherwise you have to do "nasty" workarounds in js

Comment: var body_json = jQuery.parseJSON(JSONString);

Comment: Where is the data coming from, a script of yours or an API?

Comment: If it is not your api/script generating that then you should report it to the person responsible, that json is wrong.

Comment: No. Don't build a workaround, fix the server.

Answer (score 0):

Change to like this:

```
'{"name": "abcd,e\'abc\'ssfgh", "location": {"latitude": 21.1484436189,"longitude": 79.093036862},"id": "12345"}'
```

**Pay more attention `\'` and `'{}'`**

```js
var str = '{"name": "abcd,e\'abc\'ssfgh", "location": {"latitude": 21.1484436189,"longitude": 79.093036862},"id": "12345"}';

var json = jQuery.parseJSON(str);
$('div').text(json);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>123</div>
```